# SSRS number format for to show -$9,123

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying apply number format for a range of  cells at once using format property (rather than changing the format by going into each cell separately).

So far I've managed to use the code C0 so now positive number show $5,789 but negative numbers show ($5,789)

What I want is negative numbers showing as -$5,789

Anyone know what format code to use instead on C0

thanks

Comment: currency don't have negative value. :)

Comment: you can try something like this if you really want to display the negative sign. =IIf(Fields!col1.Value < 0, "-" + Fields!col1.Value.ToString("C0"), Fields!col1.Value.ToString("C0"))

Comment: Currency do have a negative value.

Comment: **This is NOT a duplicate of that other question.** The ANSWER of that question does show how someone could change it but doesn't show it explicitly. The answer is that your LOCALE determines how currency is shown. If you do not want the default formatting with the C0 format, you must use a custom one using `'$'0,.00` or use the Text Box Properties' Number tab.

Comment: Right click on your expression > PlaceHolder Properties > Number > Currency > Choose format -$12345.00